# Can't start mongodb-community - error 12288

Tags: database, mongodb, mongo-shell

I was able to start mongodb-community server 2 days ago but now I cannot. I do not remember making any changes on it. At some point I have changed my node version to an old one but changed it back to newer one already. So I don't think that should be a problem. I use
`brew services restart mongodb-community`

and I get this error when I want to check with
`brew services list`

```
Name              Status       User File
mongodb-community error  12288 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

I checked my logs using
`tail $(brew --prefix)/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

What I get is this below:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.665+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":14790,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"SamsMacbook.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.665+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.665+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.3.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.665+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.668+03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.668+03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1120}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:40:18.668+03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.606+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.608+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.623+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.627+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":15254,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"SamsMacbook.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.3.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.629+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.634+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.635+03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.636+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.639+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.639+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.640+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.640+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.640+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.640+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.640+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-15T21:43:10.641+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

I don't know what the problem is. Can you guys please help me to solve this error 12288 problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need a few lines earlier from the log.  The first line there implies the shutdown is already in progress, a little bit earlier might reveal _why_ it is shutting down

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my logs in the post.

Comment: `"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}` Probably a mismatch between what user the service is trying to start as and running it as `root` at some point in time. Should be lots of associated questions/answers regarding that error message that can help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the mongodb service and delete the **mongodb-27017.sock** file from **/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock**.

After, start the service with running command below.

```
 brew services start mongodb-community
```